# Is it possible to dynamically create the larger image in fancy box?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm following up on a previous post 
([Fancy box with one image only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223130/fancy-box-with-one-image-only/22223254#22223254)) to find out if it's possible to use the thumbnail image in fancybox to dynamically create the larger image that gets displayed. I know that you can use document.createElement("IMG"); to add a larger version of an existing image to your document, or you can use target.style.width and target.style.height to change the size of an image and assign it to a different id, but I can't seem to get fancybox to access and use that larger version of the thumbnail. Do you always need 2 sizes for each image?

Here's the code I've been using. It will resize images on it's own, but it doesn't seem to work with fancybox.  I define the following javascript function, to work with the images:

```
<script>function magnify() { 
var thumbnail = document.getElementById('image_2');
var target = document.getElementById('image_2_larger');
var w = thumbnail.width;
var h = thumbnail.height;
target.style.width= w*1.5 +'px';
target.style.height= h*1.5 +'px';
</script>   

<body>
<p class="imglist">
<a id="image_2_larger" href="smallImage.jpg" 
onclick="magnify()" data-fancybox> 
<img id="image_2" src="smallImage.jpg"></a></p>
</body>
```

Clicking on the link activates the lightbox, but the id="image_2_larger" displays in its normal size.  I have confirmed that the javascript will produce a larger image if I just do this without fancybox

```
<img id="target" src="smallImage.jpg" onclick="magnify()">
<img id="thumbnail" src="smallImage.jpg">
```

Comment: Why would you want "to dynamically create the larger image"? That just does not make any sense.

Comment: it's inconvenient to have to add larger versions of each image to our database

Comment: There are lots of info about modern web development, for example, https://css-tricks.com/planning-for-responsive-images/

Answer (score 0):

`Do you always need 2 sizes for each image?` - the idea of any lightbox script is that you display resized version of image to save bandwidth, improve page load speed, etc and then use script to display images in full size without forcing user to leave webpage.

Obviously, you are not forced to create two versions of the image and you can do like this - `<a data-fancybox href="big-image.jpg"><img width="200" src="big-image.jpg" /></a>`, but that is not practical.

But, if you wish to start fancybox (and have zoom effect) by using single `<img>` element, then then take a look at this demo - 
https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/JzdXxp?editors=1010

Comment: I think the problem with the code you listed is that I'm trying to increase the size of the image in the href attribute, and not in the src attribute.  I could also use some explanation of what's going on in your demo, because right now I'm not making the connection to my question.

Comment: Could you translate "increase the size of the image in the href"?

Comment: My understanding is that when you implement fancybox, the smaller image that naturally appears on the page is in the second img tag, while the larger image is brought up by clicking on the anchor tag in the first position, as shown here: `<p class="imglist"><a href="pic_large.jpg" data-fancybox> <img src="pic_small.jpg"></a> </p>`                                                                                                But your code seemed to be saying that I could use the same image in both tags, and just increase the width in the img tag in the second position.

Comment: Of course you can use the same image, anchor content can be anything, it does not matter what you put there. So, where is the problem? You do not know how to resize image using CSS or how to use width/height attributes?

Comment: I've added the code I've been using to the original post above.  As I mention there, the `<a>` tag will bring up the lightbox effect but the target image is  NOT larger than the thumbnail.   Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: I also checked to make sure that I have the basic file setup correctly.  The <head> has a link to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.6/jquery.fancybox.min.css, and after all the images, the <body> has the following <script> files: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js and https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.6/jquery.fancybox.min.js

Comment: You could try something like this to enlarge small image `<a data-fancybox data-width="1800" data-height="1200" href="smallImage.jpg"> <img src="smallImage.jpg"></a>`, but that does not make any sense, you should do it the opposite - `<a data-fancybox href="bigmage.jpg"> 
<img src="bigmage.jpg" style="width:200px;"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

The opposite strategy suggested in Janis's last comment seems to work.  Instead of trying to use the thumbnail and magnify it, you can just use the larger image and shrink it, as shown here.

```
<script>
  function shrinkImage() {
    var thumbnail = document.getElementById('image_2');
    var w = thumbnail.width;
    var h = thumbnail.height;
    thumbnail.style.width = w*0.5 +'px';
    thumbnail.style.height = h*0.5 +'px';
    return;
  }
</script>

<body>
  <p class="imglist">
    <a href="largerImage.jpg" data-fancybox>
    <img id="image_2" src="largerImage.jpg" onload="shrinkImage()"></a>
  </p>
</body>
```